# How to implement Agora Audio call in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase, chat, videocall

I am new to Flutter and I want to implement 1/1 call functionality for my users. What is the best way to make calls and send call invitation.

I watched a tutorial on YouTube about WhatsApp clone that used Heroku as server. But since Heroku is no longer free. Are there any alternatives to Heroku and why do we even need a server?

Answer (score 0):

for the agora audio calling feature, you can use FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging) or Sockets to send the invitation .

I personally prefer custom sockets to implement the calling functionality.
and I've used the sockets using [socket.io](https://socket.io/)